# Segmentation fault when trying to import caffe2.python

Tags: python-2.7, caffe2

Segmentation fault when trying to import caffe2.python
on google colab with python = 2.7 , cuda 10 , cudnn 7.5

I have tried with cuda 9 and error is :
libcudart.9.so cannot open shared object

!wget https://anaconda.org/pytorch/pytorch/1.1.0/download/linux-64/pytorch-1.1.0-py2.7_cuda10.0.130_cudnn7.5.1_0.tar.bz2

!tar xvjf pytorch-1.1.0-py2.7_cuda10.0.130_cudnn7.5.1_0.tar.bz2

!cp -r lib/python2.7/site-packages/* /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/

## To check if Caffe2 build was successful

!python -c 'from caffe2.python import core' 2>/dev/null && echo "Success" || echo "Failure"

!python -c 'from caffe2.python import workspace; print(workspace.NumCudaDevices())'

Error is :

/bin/bash: line 1:
409 Segmentation fault      (core dumped) python -c 'from caffe2.python import core' 2> /dev/null

Failure

WARNING:root:
This caffe2 python run does not have GPU support. Will run in CPU only mode.

Expected :

Success

1